# How to have focus on a form when this same form open another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, i'm setting a typing application, and there's a pause key that stop a timer and prevent you from typing unless you exit the "pause" state.
This "pause" state grant you access to 2 other buttons, one called "Help"
and the other one, well he isn't very important for this questions.

When I click on "Help" a form containing some help informations open, when i closed the help form, i can't exit the pause state when i press on the pause button, it's like i've lost the focus or the program can't exit the code from the help button (The main forms doesn't close when the help forms open.)

Here's my help button

```
private void btnAide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           HelpForm fE = new HelpForm();
           fE.Visible = true;
           this.Activate();

       }
```

Here's what happen when I hit the pause key

```
 case Keys.OemQuestion:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "°"; }
                            else
                            {
                                if (timer1.Enabled)
                                {
                                    timer1.Stop();
                                    plPanneauMot.Enabled = false;
                                    btnAide.Enabled = true;
                                    btnCritereMedaille.Enabled = true;
                                    bPause = true;
                                    bPauseTouche = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    timer1.Start();
                                    plPanneauMot.Enabled = true;
                                    btnAide.Enabled = false;
                                    btnCritereMedaille.Enabled = false;
                                    bPause = false;
                                    bPauseTouche = true;
                                }
                            }
```

And... Here's my code for catching key stroke

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Colorie les touches selon leur disposition sur le clavier
                if (bPause == true)
                {
                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemQuestion)
                    {
                        bPause = false;
                        bPauseTouche = false;
                        plPanneauMot.Enabled = true;
                        btnCritereMedaille.Enabled = false;
                        btnAide.Enabled = false;
                        timer1.Start();
                    }
                }
                else if (bPause == false)
                {
                    bPauseTouche = false;
                    // Récupère la valeur de chaque touche appuyé ainsi que les trema, circonflexe, majuscule, etc.
                    switch (e.KeyCode)
                    {
                        case Keys.A:
                            if (bCirconflexe == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Â"; } // Circonflexe majuscule
                            else if (bTrema == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ä"; } // Trema majuscule
                            else if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "A"; } // Majuscule
                            else if (bCirconflexe)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "â"; } // Circonflexe minuscule
                            else if (bTrema)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ä"; } // Trema minuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "a"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.B:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "B"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "b"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.C:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "C"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "c"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "D"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "d"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.E:
                            if (bCirconflexe == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ê"; } // Circonflexe majuscule
                            else if (bTrema == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ë"; } // Trema majuscule
                            else if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "E"; } // Majuscule
                            else if (bCirconflexe)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ê"; } // Circonflexe minuscule
                            else if (bTrema)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ë"; } // Trema minuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "e"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.F:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "F"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "f"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.G:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "G"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "g"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.H:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "H"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "h"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.I:
                            if (bCirconflexe == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Î"; } // Circonflexe majuscule
                            else if (bTrema == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ï"; } // Trema majuscule
                            else if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "I"; } // Majuscule
                            else if (bCirconflexe)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "î"; } // Circonflexe minuscule
                            else if (bTrema)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ï"; } // Trema minuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "i"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.J:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "J"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "j"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.K:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "K"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "k"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.L:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "L"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "l"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.M:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "M"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "m"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.N:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "N"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "n"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.O:
                            if (bCirconflexe == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ô"; } // Circonflexe majuscule
                            else if (bTrema == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ö"; } // Trema majuscule
                            else if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "O"; } // Majuscule
                            else if (bCirconflexe)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ô"; } // Circonflexe minuscule
                            else if (bTrema)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ö"; } // Trema minuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "o"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.P:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "P"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "p"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Q:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Q"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "q"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.R:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "R"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "r"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.S:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "S"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "s"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.T:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "T"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "t"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.U:
                            if (bShift == true && bCirconflexe == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ù"; } // Accent grave minuscule
                            else if (bCirconflexe == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Û"; } // Circonflexe majuscule
                            else if (bTrema == true && bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Ü"; } // Trema majuscule
                            else if (bShift == true && bCirconflexe == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ù"; } // Accent grave minuscule
                            else if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "U"; } // Majuscule
                            else if (bCirconflexe)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "û"; } // Circonflexe minuscule
                            else if (bTrema)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ü"; } // Trema minuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "u"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.V:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "V"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "v"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.W:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "W"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "w"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.X:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "X"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "x"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Y:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Y"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "y"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Z:
                            if (bShift == true || bCapital == true)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "Z"; } // Majuscule
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "z"; } // Minuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D0:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "="; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "0"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D1:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "+"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "1"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D2:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "\""; }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "@"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "2"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D3:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "*"; }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "#"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "3"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D4:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ç"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "4"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D5:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "%"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "5"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D6:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "&"; } // Ne fonctionne pas car elle ne s'affiche pas
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "6"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D7:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "/"; }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "|"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "7"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D8:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "("; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "8"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.D9:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = ")"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "9"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Space:
                            strToucheAppuyee = " ";
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.OemPeriod:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = ":"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "."; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Oemcomma:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = ";"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = ","; }
                            BoolFalse(); ;
                            break;
                        case Keys.OemOpenBrackets:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "?"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "'"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.OemMinus:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "_"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "-"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Oem7:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ö"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "é"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Oem5:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ä"; }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "{"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "à"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Oem1: // è
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "ü"; }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "["; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "è"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Oem8:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "£"; }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "}"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "$"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.OemBackslash:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = ">"; }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "\\"; }
                            else
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "<"; }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.OemQuestion:
                            if (bShift)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "°"; }
                            else
                            {
                                if (timer1.Enabled)
                                {
                                    timer1.Stop();
                                    plPanneauMot.Enabled = false;
                                    btnAide.Enabled = true;
                                    btnCritereMedaille.Enabled = true;
                                    bPause = true;
                                    bPauseTouche = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    timer1.Start();
                                    plPanneauMot.Enabled = true;
                                    btnAide.Enabled = false;
                                    btnCritereMedaille.Enabled = false;
                                    bPause = false;
                                    bPauseTouche = true;
                                }
                            }
                            BoolFalse();
                            break;
                        case Keys.Oemtilde: // Les 2 points, ex : ë
                            if (bShift)
                            {
                                strToucheAppuyee = "!";
                                BoolFalse();
                            }
                            else if (bAltGr)
                            { strToucheAppuyee = "]"; }
                            else
                            {
                                BoolFalse();
                                bTrema = true;
                                bPasErreur = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case Keys.Oem6: // ^ Ex : ê
                            if (bAltGr)
                            {
                                strToucheAppuyee = "~";
                                BoolFalse();
                            }
                            else if (bShift)
                            {
                                BoolFalse();
                                bShift = true;
                                bCirconflexe = true;
                                bPasErreur = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                BoolFalse();
                                bCirconflexe = true;
                                bPasErreur = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case Keys.ShiftKey: // Shift
                            BoolFalse();
                            bShift = true;
                            bPasErreur = true;
                            break;
                        case Keys.ControlKey: // Ctrl
                            BoolFalse();
                            bCtrl = true;
                            bPasErreur = true;
                            if (bAlt)
                            { bAltGr = true; }
                            break;
                        case Keys.Menu: // Alt
                            BoolFalse();
                            bAlt = true;
                            bPasErreur = true;
                            if (bCtrl)
                            { bAltGr = true; }
                            break;
                        case Keys.Capital: // Majuscule
                            BoolFalse();
                            if (bCapital)
                            {
                                bCapital = false;
                                lblMajActiver.Visible = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bCapital = true;
                                lblMajActiver.Visible = true;
                            }
                            bPasErreur = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    // Calcul le nombre de lettre par minute
                    dblLPMMoyenne = dblLPM * 60 / dblSecondeLPM;
                    lblLettreMinuteChiffre.Text = Convert.ToString(dblLPMMoyenne = Math.Round(dblLPMMoyenne, 2));

                    // S'il appuie sur une lettre spécial (Trema, AltGr, Alt, Pause, Shift, etc.) il ne fait rien
                    if (bPasErreur == true)
                    { }
                    // Sinon il vérifie que la touche est la bonne et la transforme en blanc pour l'effacer mais pas entièrement
                    else if (strToucheAppuyee == _lettres_liste.ElementAt(iLettreAppuyeeCompteur) && bPause == false)
                    {
                        if (iLettreAppuyeeCompteur != iCharCompteur - 1)
                        {
                            SwitchCouleur();
                        }
                        if (bErreurUnique == false)
                        {
                            _nomLabel.ElementAt(iLettreAppuyeeCompteur).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        { _nomLabel.ElementAt(iLettreAppuyeeCompteur).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray; }
                        _nomLabel.ElementAt(iLettreAppuyeeCompteur).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        iLettreAppuyeeCompteur++;
                        bErreurUnique = true;
                        dblLPM++;
                    }
                    // Si c'est faux il rajoute une erreur et fait en sorte avec bErreurUnique que il ne puisse pas faire faux plus d'une fois à la même lettre
                    else
                    {
                        _nomLabel.ElementAt(iLettreAppuyeeCompteur).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        if (bErreurUnique)
                        { iNbErreur++; }
                        bErreurUnique = false;
                        lblNombreFauteChiffre.Text = iNbErreur.ToString();
                    }
                    // Si le nombre de lettre appuyé est égal au nombre de lettre total, il arrête l'exercice et affiche la suite
                    if (iLettreAppuyeeCompteur == iCharCompteur || System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"../../../../../Texte/ExercicePersonnel.txt") == "true" && iLettreAppuyeeCompteur == iCharCompteur - 2)
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();
                        btnResultat.Visible = true;
                        lblExerciceFini.Visible = true;
                        for (int i = 0; i <= _nomLabel.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (_nomLabel.ElementAt(i).ForeColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                            { }
                            else
                            { _nomLabel.ElementAt(i).ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText; }
                            _nomLabel.ElementAt(i).BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            { }

        }
```

Comment: See my two form project :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: can you show the code from the pause button

Comment: Is there a loop or a timer running maybe ? How do you close the help form ? We need much more information in order to help with this

Comment: There's in fact a timer running, but when you hit the pause button it should stop.
And you close it manually by clicking the red cross on the top right
@GuidoG

Comment: so what happens if you put a breakpoint at the first line of code in the `click` event of the pause button. Does it hits when you click on it after opening/closing the help form ?

Comment: When I hit the key for the pause, it reach the pause code 1 time but after opening/closing the help form it doesn't reach there anymore

Comment: You say `the key for the pause` So its not a button but you are catching key strokes ? In that case, show the code how you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you are catching key strokes on your main form.
So that is why you call `this.Activate()` after opening the help form.

However, once the user does anything at the help form, just clicking on it, the main form will lose focus.

So you need to pass a handle to your main form to the help form, and when closing the help form you can use this handle to re-activate the main form.

in your help form, write a constructor like this

```
private Form _mainForm = null;

public HelpForm(Form mainForm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _mainForm = mainForm;
}

// subscribe to the FormClosed event, and use this code
private void HelpForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     if (_mainForm != null)
        _mainForm.Activate();  
)
```

now in your mainform call it like this

```
private void btnAide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelpForm fE = new HelpForm(this);
    fE.Visible = true;
    this.Activate();
}
```

EDIT
Another method that could help is Activating the main form, every time the help form gets deactivated

```
// subscribe to the Deactivate event on the help form
private void FormBase_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (_mainForm != null)
        _mainForm.Activate();  
}
```

Comment: This is maybe the answer, but when i place some breakpoints, i just saw that my program can't go in `HelpForm_FormClosed`

Comment: How do you close that form ?

Comment: With the red cross on windows

Comment: Is there some code in the `FormClosing` event maybe that prevents the form from actually closing ? Or some other code that makes it so that the form only hides, not really closes ?

Comment: Not in there, my help forms don't have much code in it, in fact there's only your code in it now

Comment: well something is preventing the `FormClosed` event from firing. How did you subscribed to this event ?

Comment: How do i see that ?

Comment: Open the form in the designer, then use the `Properties` window where you can see all properties for the form. In the events (the icon with the lightning bold) find the event `FormClosing` and doubleclick on it. If you did not subscribed to it yet, it will now make a new method. Put my code in that method

Comment: The event `FormClosing` or the event `FormClosed` ? Cause the code that you have written it's writted "FormCLosedEventArgs"

Comment: The event `FormClosed`

Comment: It doesn't work, the breakpoints tell me that `HelpForm_FormClosed` is entered, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Test it without breakpoints now, since stopping at your breakpoint will again cause your main form to loose focus

Comment: On the main form, create an `Activated` event and for testing put code there like `MessageBox.Show("i am active");` Does that shows after closing your helpform ?

Comment: I wrote an Edit in my answer, maybe that helps more

Answer (score 0):

When you close the help window add the command ".Focus()" to the pause control.